# How can I be sure that subclass set a (mandatory) property in it's constructor?

Tags: design, design-patterns, object-oriented, php, object-oriented-design

I have a base class called ProductRepository and there are other classes which extends it; such as PushProductRepository or SocialProductRepository.

```
class ProductRepository implements ProductRepositoryInterface
{
    private $product;

    public function __construct(Product $product)
    {
        $this->product = $product;
    }

    public function create($name, $language, $type)
    {
        $this->product->create([
            'name' => $name,
            'language' => $language,
            'type' => $type
        ]);
    }
}
```

As you can see there is a **type** parameter in create function. It may be the values such as 'push' or 'social'. It will take the value from the classes which extends it. Instead of sending it as a parameter; I want to have a different approach. I will create a property in ProductRepository such as type and use $this->type in create function.

But I want to be sure that every class that extends ProductRepository should set this property in it's own class (probably in it's constructor)

How can I be sure that every class that extends ProductRepository will set **type** in it's constructor ? Is there any better way to achieve this? Is this violates anything? If it is so, how can i prevent it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without delving into whether it's good or bad approach and just answering the question `how?`, I would make `ProductRepository` abstract, with abstract `getType()` method. So it would look like the following:

```
abstract class ProductRepository
{
    private $product;

    public function __construct(Product $product)
    {
        $this->product = $product;
    }

    public function create($name, $language, $type)
    {
        $this->product->create([
            'name' => $name,
            'language' => $language,
            'type' => $this->getType()
        ]);
    }

    abstract protected function getType();
}
```

As far as I can tell, type has something to do with a product itself, that is, with domain, so I would discourage building this logic in repository. What about creating a product with specific `type` property? It looks way cleaner for me -- at least domain logic resides in domain. And I don't understand why `create` method belongs to `product`. Probably you should have `ProductRepository` looking like that:

```
class ProductRepository
{
    private $dataStorage;

    public function __construct(DataStorage $dataStorage)
    {
        $this->dataStorage = $dataStorage;
    }

    public function add(Product $product)
    {
        $this->dataStorage
            ->insert(
                $product->getName(),
                $product->getLanguage(),
                $product->getType()
            )
        ;
    }
}
```

Comment: Product is a model (orm) and in that case create method is it's own method. What should i do when i need to instantiate ProductRepository ?

Comment: Um, what ORM are you using? I just can't realize why on Earth you need to call `create` method on an entity, and moreover, pass the entities properties as arguments. Why, if you already have them within that entity?

Comment: > What should i do when i need to instantiate ProductRepository ?
Typically you need some DAL (like [Doctrine's](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/dbal.html)), or just [PDO](http://php.net/manual/book.pdo.php).

Comment: It is eloquent (laravel) and model is injected and it doesn’t have a knowledge about it’s properties, so i don’t have them in my model. When i said about instantiating i mean  I can’t instantiate an abstract class if i turn it into concrete one then I can’t use abstract method ?